# XCode Instruments 6 (by far) not reflecting the correct amount of memory

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, instruments

I've a huge difference between the amount of used memory displayed in XCode debug panel and the same info in Instruments.
XCode shows 400 MB of allocated memory when Instruments only shows 42MB. I'm certainly closer to 400 than 42 as I've multiples 32MB textures loaded... (And this time, 42 is not the answer, btw)

XCode 6.0.1, iPad 3, iPhone 5S, iOS 7.1.2 on both, Profiling on real devices, but no problem doing the same thing on simulator.

Not an ideal situation to track memory consumption.

What goes wrong? Did I miss something? I filter on "All allocations" and "All heap and anonymous".
Any idea ? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Allocations instrument doesn't record OpenGL ES texture memory allocations. If your app is allocating multiple 32 MB textures, that would explain why Xcode is reporting memory usage of 400 MB and the Allocations instrument is reporting 42 MB.

Use the OpenGL ES Analysis template to look at your texture memory allocations. Use the Allocations instrument to look at the rest of your app's memory allocations.

Comment: Interesting and a bit surprising as Instruments don't work that way with the simulator currently. I did a try but can't find where these allocs are traced in the OpenGL ES Instruments module. What I need is track and backtrace the alloc calls like it's done for all other mems allocs (through the Allocations module). Any clue?

Comment: I don't think you can trace allocs with the OpenGL ES instruments. Those instruments trace OpenGL ES calls. The OpenGL ES Analyzer instrument lets you graph uploaded texture bytes. The GPU Driver instrument has several texture-related statistics for you to graph.

Answer (score 0):

Found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15536861/2292348

I think the activity monitor can be used to show real memory usage: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html

Comment: Activity monitor is of no use to track *where* my memory goes. As I said, I trust what XCode debug panel tells but Instruments is there to dig deeper with more granularity into the malloc()s, and currently it doesn't show the real state of my app, just a small subset of the allocations.