# Allocation Instrument Not Showing True Memory Usage & App Crashing

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, memory-management, xcode-instruments

I am making an iPhone app which lets the user create and store up to 4 images.

However the app sometimes crashes anywhere between taking 2-20 pictures (as in taking some pictures, deleting them, taking them again etc).

The problem is my app will crash at some point without a memory warning, stack trace, or anything.

When I run my instruments tool, I see that my allocations don't seem to get even half way to the allowed memory usage. But I KNOW the only reason you get crashes without messages means a very fast over-use of total app memory.

So my question is:
Is there something else to the Allocations instrument I can dig into to get my 'true' app allocation amount?

Clearly something is hogging my memory and the default allocations instrument I am using is not showing me what I need.

Comment: Have you tried the "Leaks" tool or "VMTracker"? They are pretty useful when it comes to finding memory issues. Sometimes, "Allocations" won't show any problems at all but VMTracker might have the answer. Look for Dirty Memory (i.e. Heap allocations, decompressed images, caches, etc.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode Instruments 6 (by far) not reflecting the correct amount of memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000809/xcode-instruments-6-by-far-not-reflecting-the-correct-amount-of-memory)