# Why would Xcode show MUCH more memory use than Instruments for SceneKit app?

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I'm trying to debug why our SceneKit-based app is using so much memory but Xcode and Instruments / Allocations seem to have very different values for the amount of memory being used. When I look in Xcode I see something like **600 MB** but when I transfer the same running session over to Instruments / Allocations, I see a very different number for persistent bytes, like **150 MB**.

Which one is correct? Why the difference? Are they measuring different things?

(Regardless of whether I Transfer an Xcode debug session or start fresh in Instruments, it doesn't seem to make much difference.)

[image: Xcode screenshot][image: Instruments screenshot]

The reason that I care is that iOS is killing the app for excessive memory use (according to Xcode) but I can't seem to find the problem via Instruments.

I've tried turning off all GPU and Metal debug options but they don't seem to make a difference.

[image: Xcode debug scheme options][image]

Comment: “Are they measuring different things?” Very possibly. Measure a Release build on the device. Do not measure in the simulator, and do not measure a Debug build, as you will get totally wrong memory usage info.

Comment: Thanks Matt, but I should have included in my original question that I've tried both Debug and Release builds and the numbers for Release are within 1-2MB in each case  compared with the Debug builds. I also only run on a device and never run on the simulator since on the simulator, SceneKit performance is not usable nor does it support PBR.

Comment: Ok, well in that case I’d say the simple answer is: believe Instruments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which one is correct?

My intuition is: Instruments. It uses Dtrace to (sorry) instrument your code and watch actual allocations and deallocations as they happen, at the expense of performance. The Xcode debug navigator memory graph is more of an outside view designed to give a very general sense of what’s happening. That is exactly why the latter offers you a way to switch to the former — because that (Instruments) is where you’re going to get real measurements.

(However, let’s keep in mind that Instruments may fail to include in the total you’re seeing some virtual memory backing stores for graphics. There are plenty of WWDC videos discussing this topic in more detail. )

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. The one thing I could find is how to use the Xcode Capture GPU Frame command. That shows a list of the current textures and buffers, but I haven't found anything that shows a total of the memory or VM used by them. However, doing some rough addition for an empty SCNView, I can total up about 50MB of screen-sized RGBA and BGRA textures, but the total memory use that Xcode is showing is 211MB and Instruments shows a total of 43MB. So there still seems to be a lot of memory either unaccounted for or miscalculated by Xcode / iOS.

Comment: But what about the VMTracker instrument?  And see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536557/xcode-instruments-allocation-tool-misses-quite-a-bit.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, the memory turns out to be resident / dirty VM and it's visible via VM Tracker. This blog post was a good starting point for understanding it: http://liam.flookes.com/wp/2012/05/03/finding-ios-memory/ and the iOS Memory Deep Dive talk at WWDC 2018, https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/416/ has a lot more detail. Unfortunately, the vast majority of VM is allocated by IOKit, so it's probably texture images.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this answer is quite late, but for the sake of future developers with the same problem, I would advise you to check the images in your assets folder. If any of your images have dimensions larger than 1000 x 1000 you should scale them down. With the example above, the image comprises of 1000000 pixels. Following how images are loading in (4 bytes per pixel), this means 4 MB of memory is used to load the image. Unbeknownst to me, I had an image of roughly 3600 * 4000 in my assets folder. Doing the maths, this was over 50 MB of memory usage!